# Pandas timeseries manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some data in the following format:

```
id  1234    5678    9876    
date                                                                                    
2017-10-22 11:12:21.926000000   NaN     NaN     NaN     
2017-10-22 11:16:34.589000000   NaN     5       NaN
2017-10-22 11:20:45.192000000   NaN     NaN     10 
2017-10-22 11:22:22.361000000   12      NaN     NaN 
2017-10-22 11:25:25.034000000   NaN     8       NaN
```

I want to clean this data into proper minute by minute time series and carry forwad the values for every minute till a new value is found for the ID in the time, "for the needed time range".

Output:

```
id  1234    5678    9876    
date                                                                                    
2017-10-22 11:12:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     
2017-10-22 11:13:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     
2017-10-22 11:14:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     
2017-10-22 11:15:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     
2017-10-22 11:16:00     NaN     5       NaN
2017-10-22 11:17:00     NaN     5       NaN
2017-10-22 11:18:00     NaN     5       NaN
2017-10-22 11:19:00     NaN     5       NaN
2017-10-22 11:20:00     NaN     5       10 
2017-10-22 11:21:00     NaN     5       10 
2017-10-22 11:22:00     12      5       10 
2017-10-22 11:23:00     12      5       10 
2017-10-22 11:24:00     12      5       10 
2017-10-22 11:25:00     12      8       10 
2017-10-22 11:26:00     12      8       10
```

I have been trying to create new dataframe and merge it with the old one but not with much luck. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'd' is the dataframe you show as your starting point then:

```
d.date = pd.to_datetime(d.date).values.astype('<M8[m]')
d = d.set_index('date')
d.resample('1Min').ffill().fillna(method='ffill')
```

You have to 'chop off' the seconds and fractions of seconds by calling `.values.astype('<M8[m]')` because `ffill` rounds up even for a few seconds. Also the two `ffill` calls seem weird but if you try with just one you will see that things are filled in only partially until another non-NaN value shows up in any column.

And also make sure 'date' is set as the index.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although there are some duplicates in the date section:
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit;

2017-10-07 00:00:00  NaN , 
2017-10-07 00:00:00  NaN,
This fails in the last line: d.resample('1Min').ffill().fillna(method='ffill')

Comment: Never mind since we eliminated seconds, it added duplicates, I had to regroup.